# join two dataframes in cells with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two dataframe that have the same rows and columns in python, I want to join with the following condition.

Mainteain the same structure of df_a, introduce de value of the df_b just in the cells with "x" value of the df_a

df_a =

| 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | x | x | nan | nan |
| nan | x | x | x | x | x |

df_b =

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | 8 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 6 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 | nan |

The final dataframe would be

df_final =

| 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 5 | 8 | nan | nan |
| nan | 6 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 2 |

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way ;) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {
    2022:['x', None, None] ,2023:['x', None, 'x'] ,2024:['x','x','x'] ,2025:[None, 'x', 'x'] ,2026:[None,None,'x'] ,2027:[None,None,'x']
}

b={
    1:[4,5,6],2:[7,8,9],3:[8, None, 4], 4:[None,None,3],5:[None,None,2],6:[None,None,None]
    
}
 
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)
 
 
l = []
for i in df_b.values.tolist():
    
    for j in i:
        if(type(j)==int)or(type(j)==float):
            try:
                l.append(int(j))
            except:
                pass
    

df_a[df_a.eq("x")] = l
df_a
```

Output:

```
   2022  2023 2024  2025  2026  2027
0     4     7    8  None  None  None
1  None  None    5     8  None  None
2  None     6    9     4     3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for equality for value `x` in `df_a` then assign the values of `df_b`

```py
>>> df_a[df_a.eq('x')]=df_b.values

# df_a
  2022 2023 2024 2025 2026 2027
0    4  7.0    8  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN    5  8.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  6.0    9  4.0  3.0  2.0
```

Comment: I don't get the right result when running this code. In my result only the intersection cells where a and b have 'x' are filled with numbers.

Comment: @Rabinzel OP wants the x values in a to be filled from b

Comment: yes, I know. when running your code, in `df_a`, the first row is right, 2nd row only nans, in the 3rd row only column 2023 to 2026 gets filled with numbers (that's why I said only the intersection gets filled instead of all values in that row). I am searching the mistake on my side, but I can't find one...

Comment: @Rabinzel may be you have some decripencies in df_a and df_b from what OP has provided. Or it could be due to different version of python/pandas as well

Comment: the correct input I have double and triple checked :P Propably different version then... I just wanted to check if you run the code on your side and checked it or if you just knew that it works that way (without testing it)

Comment: @Rabinzel, No No. I ran the code and confirmed the output before posting the answer

Comment: @ThePyGuy, looks like a typo in the output shared by the OP. In the last row, the values are shifted one cell to the right. When running your code, I get `2  NaN  9.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  NaN` as a last row.

Comment: @abokey there is no typo in the OP's desired output. It is the same like the last row in this answer and also what he wants. I get the same result as you and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: This may sound silly but maybe it’s because of the way we read the two dataframes. I’m using `pd.read_clipboard()` by the way.

Comment: I use a function with `pd.read_table` with a `StringIO` input as buffer. I also rebuild the df on my own and used the input created by the 3rd answer here. I ran the code with python 3.8.13 and pandas 1.4.3 in jupyterlab, aswell as in vscode in a virtual env with python 3.10.4 and pandas 1.4.4...nothing worked so far. If anyone has an idea why, I would be curious to know. Also the other solution with `pd.update` didn't work for me, which is kind of weird. Must be something on my side.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the column names of df_b the same as df_a, you can use the update functionality and leverage the filter_func parameter to update only 'x' values.

```
df_b.columns = df_a.columns
df_a.update(df_b, filter_func=lambda x: x=='x')
```